# Why doesn't md5 (and other hash algorithms) output in base32?

Tags: hash, hex, md5, sha, base32

It seems like most hashes (usually in base16/hex) could be easily represented in base32 in a lossless way, resulting in much shorter (and more easily readable) hash strings.

I understand that naive implementations might mix "O"s, "0"s, "1"s, and "I"s, but one could easily choose alphabetic characters without such problems. There are also enough characters to keep hashes case-insensitive. I know that shorter hash algorithms exist (like crc32), but this idea could be applied to those too for even shorter hashes.

**Why, then, do most (if not all) hash algorithm implementations not output in base32, or at least provide an option to do so?**